# Swift: UICollectionView into UIViewController programmatically as subclass

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I have a simple `UIViewController` and i want to place multiple `UICollectionView` (more than one) into that `UIViewController` programmatically.

[image]

I know this is entirely possible but i want to configure and implement the `UICollectionView` in subclass.

And the question is:

- How can i init and add as subview `UICollectionView` in `UIViewController`
- What type should be my subclass `UICollectionView` or `UICollectionViewController`

P.S. I don't use Storyboard or Nib and i want to do this 100% programmatically.

Thanks in advance

Comment: "P.S. I don't use Storyboard or Nib and i want to do this 100% programmatically", why being so foolish ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should look like this:

```
let controller = <your UICollectionViewController initialization>
addChildViewController(controller)
controller.view.frame = CGRectMake(...) //frame of UICollectionView you want it takes in main View
view.addSubview(controller.view)
controller.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
```

By the way, it is actually much easier if you use the "Container view" in Interface Builder. Then you don't have to worry about any of these containment-related calls, and Interface Builder will take care of it for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    let layout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 20, left: 10, bottom: 10, right: 10)
    layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: 90, height: 120)

    collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: self.view.frame, collectionViewLayout: layout)
    collectionView.dataSource = self
    collectionView.delegate = self
    collectionView.registerClass(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
    collectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    self.view.addSubview(collectionView)
}
```

It creates a `UICollectionView` programmatically. To add multiple collection view, identify them with help of `.tag`